# How to overcome the slow speed in which browsers update event.target.value

Tags: javascript, settimeout

**Background For Question:** In the simplified test code below when a key is pressed the function outputs the value of `event.target.value` to a `div` element.  The problem is that before `event.key` is added to `event.target.value` the browser has already read `event.target.value` which makes the output in the div 1 character behind.

```js
"use strict";

 document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
     document.querySelector('div').textContent = event.target.value;
 });
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div></div>
```

**One Possible Solution:** One way to overcome this is by adding `setTimeout()` inside the callback.  This works but it seems hacky because it's not possible to know the proper delay on every device at every time.

```js
"use strict";

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('div').textContent = event.target.value;
    }, 10);
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div></div>
```

**Question:** Are there additional techniques to overcome this common problem?  I'm only aware of `setTimeout()`.

Comment: does it have to be keydown?

Comment: On the script I'm working on it does have to be `keydown`.  But generally speaking this is a problem I've seen pop up quite a few times.

Comment: You say you need to listen to `keydown`...but is there a reason why you can't listen to *both* `keydown` and `input`, and use the `input` listener to update your div? That would be much more reliable than a `setTimeout`. And you could use custom properties or shared scope variables or something if you need to share data between the listeners (e.g. modifier keys being pressed etc)

Comment: @David784 you are 100% correct and that's exactly what I'm going to do.  I didn't think about using an additional `keyup`.  It's so obvious but I couldn't think of it without some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` value is being updated on `keyup` or `input` events, not on `keydown`. So if you need a value in a separate `div` you can read the `event'`s properties like `event.key`, `event.shiftKey` and so on.